# is it possible to cycle multiple sub activities on android

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to code this, i have a Main Activity with one start button  and ten sub activities, that run a countdown timer and show a picture, all ten different picture and time, when click it has to run A1 then A2, then A1 and A2 again, then A1, then A3, then A4 , then A5 , then A4 again, and so on,i added a flow chart below

[image: Flow chart of Main Activity and ten sub activities]

Comment: Launching multiple activities would be an extremely heavyweight solution for what you describe.  Why not have one activity and just change the image shown?

Comment: You can code the logic you want with a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "subactivity" in android.  All activities can be started at any time, from any other activity.  What you want to do is easy enough, you just need each Activity other than A1 to activate A1 after a timer, and you need A1 itself to keep track of what the last/next Activity it activated was, so it knows which one to activate next on *its* timer.